# How to code an assignment operator for each member of a class in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm a newcomer to C++ and I'm now trying to implement a model. Well, does it make sense to overload an assignment operator (as a setter) for each member of a class? This would be quite important if a non-member function is trying to set a new value to a private/protected data member. For instance:

```
class Human {
  private:
      double aWeight[100]; /* let's say I want to keep... 
...a set of 100 weight measures of this human.*/

    // member functions and constructors here...

    };
```

Now, let's say I have a non-member function to simulate these measurements...non-member because I have a large model and I'm implementing each equation as a small function in a model.cpp file.

```
bool ComputeWeight(Human * humanpt, double energy, int day){

  humanpt->aWeight[day] = energy * 0.8;
}
```

Now, I bring to discussion: obviously I could have a member function named setWeight(double energy, int day), and do that:

```
bool ComputeWeight(Human * humanpt, double energy, int day){
   humanpt->setWeight(energy, day);
}
```

However, when coding a large model it is very impractical to calculate new data member values and update them within the object through a set funcion. Would them be possible to code an overload of operator= to each data member of a class? So I would have my own operator= for member aWeight, proceeding my Compute function exactly as in the first example?

Comment: `an assignment operator (as a setter)` These are two different things. Are you asking about the assignment operator or about setter functions?

Comment: When you go `a = b;` there is no room in the operator syntax to specify which internal member of `a` is to be undated. Also it is more usual to pass by reference rather than pointer. **ADD:** you can make `ComputeWeight()` a friend of `Person` so it can access the private members if you need.

Comment: I'm asking about assignment operator as a setter. Maybe I'm wrong here. But, I want to set a new value to array aWeight, and I would do that with a setter, right? However, could I code operator= as a setter, so I could code my own aWeight[day] = some calculated value?

Comment: Also a method `setWeight()` will commonly only take a single value for the weight itself. If you are computing the weight from other values, it is better to choose a different name such as `computeWeight()`.

Comment: `I'm asking about assignment operator as a setter.` This makes absolutely no sense. "assignment operator" and "setter" are two very different things.

Comment: @Galik, yes I think it would be more OOA and C++ making a friend of my class to access private data!

Comment: `could I code operator= as a setter, so I could code my own aWeight[day] = some calculated value` No, you cannot do this in C++.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice can you briefly point to me the main difference (setter vs. assingment)? thanks, as I said, I'm very new into C++...

Comment: setters are member functions, assignment is an operator (the = symbol)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you want to do. Could you give an example of the syntax as you would like it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does it make sense to overload an assignment operator (as a setter) for each member of a class?

C++ doesn't allow you to overload the assignment operator for individual members. The only way to assign to members directly is to make them public and then the assignment operator is overloaded based on the member's type, not the containing class.

On the other hand, you can (and sometimes should) provide setter methods for members of a class.

I think you are conflating assignment operator (eg `c = 10;`) with a setter method (such as `c.setWeight(10);`. These are two entirely different things.

**Addendum:**

Assignment operators are made to copy the data of one object to the data of another object. The only way to allow setting a member variable directly with an assignment operator is to declare that member as public. In Object Oriented Programming, this is frowned upon because it breaks encapsulation and data hiding.

Comment: *"C++ doesn't allow you to overload the assignment operator for individual members"* I'd like to add that even if you could, it would lead to ambiguity. What if there were two members that were both `int`? The function signature would look identical, even if the actual definitions did different work, the compiler would throw an error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, Thanks for your note. I understand the difference of assignment operator and setters (member functions), but I thought that just for a sake of ease of coding I could declare my own operator= as a setter within a given class. Your explanation really helped me!